# Getting one value from a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

Is there a way to get one value from a tuple in Python using expressions?

```
def tup():
  return (3, "hello")

i = 5 + tup()  # I want to add just the three
```

I know I can do this:

```
(j, _) = tup()
i = 5 + j
```

But that would add a few dozen lines to my function, doubling its length.

Comment: The `_` is also just a variable. It's just often used to assign value to it that can be discarded. But theoretically you can get the value from `_`

Answer (score 260, accepted):

You can write

```
i = 5 + tup()[0]
```

Tuples can be indexed just like lists.

The main difference between tuples and lists is that tuples are immutable - you can't set the elements of a tuple to different values, or add or remove elements like you can from a list. But other than that, in most situations, they work pretty much the same.

Answer (score 86):

For anyone in the future looking for an answer, I would like to give a much clearer answer to the question.

```
# for making a tuple
my_tuple = (89, 32)
my_tuple_with_more_values = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

# to concatenate tuples
another_tuple = my_tuple + my_tuple_with_more_values
print(another_tuple)
# (89, 32, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

# getting a value from a tuple is similar to a list
first_val = my_tuple[0]
second_val = my_tuple[1]

# if you have a function called my_tuple_fun that returns a tuple,
# you might want to do this
my_tuple_fun()[0]
my_tuple_fun()[1]

# or this
v1, v2 = my_tuple_fun()
```

Hope this clears things up further for those that need it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. For completeness, you may want to add the use of the underscore as 'dummy' placeholder in tuple unpacking.

Answer (score 9):

## General

Single elements of a tuple `a` can be accessed -in an indexed array-like fashion-

via `a[0]`, `a[1]`, ... depending on the number of elements in the tuple.

## Example

If your tuple is `a=(3,"a")`

- `a[0]` yields `3`,
- `a[1]` yields `"a"`

## Concrete answer to question

```
def tup():
  return (3, "hello")
```

`tup()` returns a 2-tuple.

In order to "solve"

```
i = 5 + tup()  # I want to add just the three
```

you select the *3* by:

```
tup()[0]    # first element
```

so all together:

```
i = 5 + tup()[0]
```

## Alternatives

Go with `namedtuple` that allows you to access tuple elements by name (and by index). Details are at https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

```
>>> import collections
>>> MyTuple=collections.namedtuple("MyTuple", "mynumber, mystring")
>>> m = MyTuple(3, "hello")
>>> m[0]
3
>>> m.mynumber
3
>>> m[1]
'hello'
>>> m.mystring
'hello'
```