# PyQt: return value of QFileDialog.getOpenFileName

Tags: python, pyqt, return-type, qfiledialog

```
file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
```

I have used the above to get the path of a file. The output is:

```
('D:/test images/test13.jpg', '')
```

What should i do to get the output as: `'D:/test images/test13.jpg'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting one value from a python tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136059/getting-one-value-from-a-python-tuple)

Comment: Even if you didn't know this was a tuple, a title like "Get only path of file from QFileDialog.getOpenFileName" would be much better than "Python GUI PyQt".

Answer (score 1):

`QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()` in PyQt5 [is the same](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#qfiledialog) as [`QFileDialog.getOpenFileNameAndFilter()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileNameAndFilter) in PyQt4, it returns the file name and the filter selected by the user. You can use

```
file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]
```

to get only the file, or

```
file, filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
```

which I find clearer because it's immediately obvious what the method returns.