# Appending max value of a zipped list

Tags: python-3.x, list, max

I have these three lists:

```
bankNames = ["bank1","bank2","bank3"]
interestRate = (0.05,0.01,0.08)
namePlusInterest = zip(interestRate,bankNames)

print(max(list(namePlusInterest)))
```

the print function returns an output of:

```
(0.08, 'bank3')
```

I want to be able to split the output into individual variables (for example):

```
MaxRate = 0.08
MaxBank = 'bank3'
```

So for later in my code I can say:

```
print(MaxBank + "has the highest interest rate of" + MaxRate)
```

Comment: `zip[interestRate,bankNames]` must be `zip(interestRate,bankNames)`. The result is a tuple. Extract itrs first and second elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting one value from a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136059/getting-one-value-from-a-tuple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *tuple unpacking* to get each individual element from the tuple:

```
bankNames = ["bank1", "bank2", "bank3"]
interestRate = (0.05, 0.01, 0.08)

namePlusInterest = zip(interestRate, bankNames)

MaxRate, MaxBank = max(list(namePlusInterest))

print(f"{MaxBank} has the highest interest rate of {MaxRate}")
```

Comment: thank you, this really helped me with my assignment