# How to remove multiple values from a tuple in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have a tuple which is an output of a select query. The tuple looks like this:

`('checkStatus id              \n========================= ==================== \nfalse adcs-fddf-sdsd \n', None)`

I am trying to retrieve only the two values i.e. false and adcs-fddf-sdsd

This is the code:

```
import subprocess

def foo():
  cmd = return ("select checkStatus , id from abc") 
  pr = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=TRUE)
  output = pr.communicate()
  print(output)          //('checkStatus id              \n========================= 
                         //      ==================== \nfalse adcs-fddf-sdsd \n', None)
```

Now, I found out that I can use replace to remove the unwanted white space using `str(output).replace(' ', '')`. So, for all the other details also I will have to add multiple replace statements. So, is there a better way to retrieve only those 2 values `(false and adcs-fddf-sdsd)` .

**NOTE** The code has to be compatible for both Python version 2 and 3.

Comment: The posted code has syntax error(s).

Comment: On one hand you ask about parsing a string and getting specific parts of it, on the other hand you give us some code that doesn't make any sense. Please [edit] and either fix those errors in your code or just remove it and ask about extracting information from that string. Also some feedback: I don't know why you want to use `subprocess.Popen` to talk to whatever database you are using but there are better ways to do that by using dedicated libraries / packages for the same, these would also remove the need for you to parse the output string..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your output is always in a similar form you could get the position of the last `\n` (let's call it `x`) and the one before that (let's call it `y`).
You can retrieve this with "rfind" ([rfind](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_rfind.asp)) and then split the result to get a list with `false` and `adcs-fddf-sdsd`.

```
output = pr.communicate()[0]
x = output.rfind('\n')
y = output.rfind('\n', 0, x)
print(output[y:x].split())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried but I am getting this error `'tuple' object has no attribute 'rfind'`

Comment: @pranami See: [Getting one value from a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136059/getting-one-value-from-a-tuple)...

Comment: Because in your case `output` is in fact, your big string and `None`. Juste use `output[0]` to get your string. I've just eddited the code snippet. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve only the two values "false" and "adcs-fddf-sdsd" from the output tuple of your SQL query, you can use regular expressions to parse the string. This approach allows you to extract specific patterns from the text regardless of the presence of whitespace or other formatting characters. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this: